# how to get images from word docx in java?

Tags: java, web-scraping

I want to make a code which will take images from a **Word file** and then save them in to some folder.

Is it possible in java? If yes then what will be APIs?

If not possible then same case  from **pdf/html** ?

I need some help to start the code. While i have no idea how to deal with this type of stuff.

Comment: can you use Apache-POI ?

Comment: Is it only for Docs ? or for pdf and html too ?

Comment: its for docs, ppt etc... link:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_POI